# JQuery DataTable Page Length Not Being Honored After Page 1

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datatables

I have a JQuery data table that has a large amount of data. I set the page length, but whenever I go past the first page, it does not honor the the length anymore.

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

As you can see, the page length is 50 which honored on the first page, but after that, the length is no longer honored.

This is my script:

```
dataTable = $("#sampleTable").DataTable({
      "ajax": {
       "url": '....',
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataSrc": ""
    },
 "columns": [
          {"data": "name", "title": "Name"},
          {"data": "value", "title": "Value"}
],
     "order": [[1, 'desc']],
     "createdRow": function(tr, _, rowIndex) {
        return $(tr).attr('rowindex', rowIndex)
      },
     "bDestroy": true,
     "pageLength": 50,
     "lengthMenu": [ 10, 15, 20 , 30, 50],
   });
```

The version I am using is jquery 1.21.1 and datatables 1.10.21

Update: As requested, this is what get's called by the ajax call

```
    @PostMapping(value = Paths.SAMPLE, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<SampleData> retrieveSamples() {
        return sampleDBDao.retrieveData();
    }
```

sample.tag

```
<table id="sampleTable" class="table" style="width: 100%">
</table>
```

Is the issue because there is a large amount of data?

Comment: It looks like you're using AJAX to load the data. How have you implemented paging in your server side code?

Comment: I don't see any use of `serverSide: true` in the code, so I assume you are not using server side processing. But also, I cannot recreate your issue using your code (with an Ajax data source). Paging info works correctly for me - so, just to check: Does the code in the question represent what you are actually doing? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: it's difficult to reproduce the issue because the url is not public. Do I need to use serverSide if there is a lot of data? Is the quantity a part of the problem. I can update with the the backend and html.

Comment: The URL not being public should not be relevant. You can try to create a MRE by replacing the `ajax` section with a [JavaScript variable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) containing the same data array which is provided by the URL. (Also, I see no reason why you are using `"bDestroy": true`, unless there is something you are doing, which needs this - and which is not shown in the question).